# Computing $\left\langle\chi^{V}, \chi^{V}\right\rangle$ in $D_3$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I am having trouble computing $\left\langle\chi^{V}, \chi^{V}\right\rangle$ in $D_3$. The character table is:
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc} 
& (E) & (R) & (S) \\
\hline D^{V} & 3 & 0 & -1
\end{array}
$$
In the notes I am following they state that $\left\langle\chi^{V}, \chi^{V}\right\rangle=2$ but I have not been able to get that result.

The definition of scalar product is given by,
$$
\langle\phi, \chi\rangle \equiv \frac{1}{[g]} \sum_{g \in G} \phi(g) \chi\left(g^{-1}\right)
$$ where $\phi$ and $\chi$ are two characters. Using this definition on for $\left\langle\chi^{V}, \chi^{V}\right\rangle$:

$$
\left\langle\chi^{V}, \chi^{V}\right\rangle = \frac{1}{6}\left(3 \cdot 3 + 0\cdot 0 + 1\cdot 1\right) = \frac{1}{6}\cdot 10
$$ which is of course not $2$. What am I doing wrong? Can someone explicitly derive it? Should I be using another definition for the scalar product?

Update: I was asked in the comments if I was looking at the right group because the table looked weird, I add a picture below:
[image: screenshot from lecture notes]

Note: This is the first time I am doing representation/group theory in a course about Symmetry in Physics and my knowledge is not too broad.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: yeah maybe, I just tried posting it but I have to wait 40 minutes till I can post another question. If it doesn't get solved here, I will try posting it in Mathematics @Qmechanic

Comment: I guess there are 3 elements in the conjugacy class of $S$? Out of curiosity, are you following the course MMP in Leiden?

Comment: That would still not solve my problem as it would give me $10/3$?
No, I am following this course in Groningen! @Mathphysmeister

Comment: The character table looks strange. Assume your $D_3$ is indeed the order-6 non-Abelian group, then the 2-dimensional rep. has character: $2$ for the identity (which is the dimension of the representation), and then $0$ and $-1$. If you calculate the inner product of this character with itself, you should get $1$. Are you sure you are looking at the correct representation?

Comment: Just added a picture of the notes I am following, as you can see they are talking about $D_3$ @MengCheng

Comment: It is the vector rep. Note that $12/6=2$. You need an additional factor 3 for $S$ conjugacy class I think. Namely $RS$, $R^2 S$ are in the same class.

Comment: @god_operator ok I thought it's an irrep. As pointed out in the other comment, the $S$ is a conjugacy class of size 3, so that will fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three elements in class $S$, one in class $E$ and two in class $R$ so summing over the group elements means there will be repeated terms in the sum:
\begin{align}
\langle \chi^V\vert \chi^V\rangle = \frac{1}{6}
\left(1\times 3^2 + 2\times 0^2 +3 \times (-1)^2\right)
=\frac{1}{6}(9+3)=2
\end{align}